# Want to make the visibility true from client side of the control which made invisible from server side

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, css

I have a text box in a page. Whose visibility is set false from the server side. Now I want to make it visible from client side by using java-script. (Any post back or partial post back can not be implemented in this case.)

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <title>ControlVisibilityClientSide</title>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function toggleVisibility(controlId)
                {
                    var control = document.getElementById(controlId);
                    if(control.style.visibility == "visible" || control.style.visibility == "")
                        control.style.visibility = "hidden";
                    else
                        control.style.visibility = "visible";
                }
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <input type="button" ID="btnShowHide" value="Show/Hide" onclick="toggleVisibility('TextBox1');" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is working fine.

But when I use

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

The above code is not working at all.

Can any one please help me out from this problem or any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you set the control `visible=false` it will not render at client side, But there is a tricky solution, that will accomplish the same thing.

In your page load, where you are set `Visible=false`, you can set the `style` to `display:none`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TextBox1.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");
}
```

It will render the control in client side, but user can't see and then you can visible the control in Javascript function to set `style Diplay:block`, LIKE...

```
document.getElementById('<%=TextBox2.ClientID %>').style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the same problem persists. Not working.

Comment: i HAVE UPDATE MY ANSWER. YOU HAVE TO SET DISPLAY = BLOCK TO VISIBLE TO YOUR CONTROL.

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar yes when I use control.style.display = 'none'; or control.style.display = 'block'; then it is working. Still I have not accepted your answer because I want to see if there is any solution for "TextBox1.Visible = false;" or not. Great effort thanks a lot.

Comment: That's what I have give you an alternate solution for visible/invisible. If you set control property visible = false, then control is not rendered, then how can you visible that particular control.

Comment: Yes I know that the control is not rendered. But there may be some kind of trick(s). I am still searching and trying if I wont find any alternate solution or some tricky interesting solution then I will must go for your solution.

Comment: Yes you are right dear. I am using your solution now. I have chosen your answer. Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: There's no solution for "TextBox1.Visible=false" because (as per VinayC's answer, which you must've seen because you put a comment under it) it stops the HTML markup for the control being sent to the client so as far as the browser and any client-side JavaScript is concerned the control doesn't exist. Muhammad's answer gives you a way to have the HTML markup for the control included in the page, but use CSS to hide/show it. With CSS you can use either 'display' or 'visibility' - for your purpose I suspect 'display' is the better option.

Answer (score 2):

Once control is marked as invisible at server side, no mark-up (html) is emitted for it. So it cannot be made visible at JS, because it (corresponding html) does not exists at client side.

Instead of making invisible at server side, you need to emit a start-up script to hide it on client side.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there any trick to do that kind of things? Because the requirement is like that only.

Answer (score 0):

set the `style["visibility"] = "hidden"` on the server side.
I.E. in c# `btnSave.style["visibility"] = "hidden";`
It will get the button rendered and therefore on the client side this element is accessible.
On the client side change the visibility style to visible.

```
$('#btnSave).css("visibility", "visible");
```