# How do i create a pop up/ dropdown calendar in Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i need to create a pop up/dropdown calendar using the asp: Calendar and textbox function.

I have tried it but when i click on the text box on the webpage it does not display the calendar.

```
<div> 
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="From: "></asp:Label> &nbsp 
         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Calendar>

        <asp:Label ID="lblTo" runat="server" Text="To: "></asp:Label> &nbsp  
         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox2_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar2" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Calendar>
</div>
```

i have also set the the calendar to visible on text change.

Comment: u have called ```visible=false``` why?

Comment: @marcelo i didnt want it to be displayed when the page loads.

Comment: ok then on your server side code ```"TextBox1_TextChanged``` call ```Calendar1.visible=true```

Comment: @marcelo done it and it does not work how it should.

Comment: yeah guessed though can u use any other library like jquery or javascript

Comment: @marcelo i dont think so man.

Comment: i have added the answer check it out

Comment: When you set a control's `Visible` property to false, it is not rendered. If you want the control to be rendered on the page but invisible until you show it, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247895/want-to-make-the-visibility-true-from-client-side-of-the-control-which-made-invi).

Answer (score 0):

call this when u want to calender to be visible in a button click or something u like

```
  protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = this.Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString();
        }
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            TextBox1.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
            Calendar1.Visible = true;
        }
```

Comment: this displays the date on the textbow but does not pop up the calendar.

Comment: updated the answer you can use this method. please On your calender control ```onselectionchanged```  event and use the code i have provided

Answer (score 0):

As textBox has no default autopostback property true,you need to set manually `AutoPostBack="True"` for textbox. so whenever textbox_text changed it server-side code run.

**WebForn Design page**

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="From: "></asp:Label> &nbsp 
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" Visible="False" OnSelectionChanged="selection_changed"></asp:Calendar>
```

**Server side**

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Calendar1.Visible = true;
}
protected void calender_selection_changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString();
    Calendar1.Visible = false;
}
```

Similarly, for textbox2 do changes

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox2_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

check here for [more info](https://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-use-autopostback-feature-in_27.html)